# How to write a python code to price a bond practically using live spot rate from the market?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-datareader

I am looking to calculate a price of a coupon bond but to discount cashflow, I need current spot rate from the market. Treasury yields are available for few maturities only. How can I price 4 year coupon bond from current treasury spot rates?

Comment: what is the data source for the market spot rate?  (is it an API or a website?)

Comment: Can fetch from Yahoo or Bloomberg